# PHP developers? rest response

Tags: php, json

Hi am i am having issues with this line of code, it is not returning JSON, could someone run this and tell me does it return json? thank you.

could someone execute this in a simple PHP client and test the response? it should return GeoJson.

```
 $response = Unirest\Request::get("https://vanitysoft-boundaries-io-v1.p.mashape.com/reaperfire/rest/v1/public/boundary?and=false&includepostal=false&limit=30&state=DC&zipcode=20002%2C20037%2C20005",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "VKyYkdzXXkmshnMjcFTCh1EZFOadp1xhlbbjsnGVgrqf759VSh",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  )
);
```

Comment: Can give more detail on what you are doing?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do (does the code above belongs to the same file or to different?). And it seems you don't understand the php basics. I see that in php block (of code you provided above) you didn't print anything - so it couldn't give you anything (even not a json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is returning a json response.

This is the exact reponse...

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20002","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.0122299194336,38.89083480834961],[-77.00822448730469,38.89141082763672],[-77.00817108154297,38.89202880859375],[-77.00590515136719,38.89201354980469],[-77.00588989257812,38.89362335205078],[-77.00757598876953,38.89362716674805],[-77.0071792602539,38.8947868347168],[-77.00906372070312,38.89479064941406],[-77.00906372070312,38.90020751953125],[-77.01217651367188,38.90019989013672],[-77.01216125488281,38.90131759643555],[-77.00906372070312,38.90131378173828],[-77.00906372070312,38.90372848510742],[-77.0110092163086,38.903785705566406],[-77.01026916503906,38.9056510925293],[-77.01216125488281,38.90626907348633],[-77.00900268554688,38.90727233886719],[-77.00902557373047,38.91078186035156],[-77.00894165039062,38.92667770385742],[-77.00629425048828,38.92700958251953],[-77.00057220458984,38.92559051513672],[-77.00057220458984,38.92237091064453],[-76.99620056152344,38.922332763671875],[-76.99563598632812,38.92536163330078],[-76.99513244628906,38.923797607421875],[-77.0013427734375,38.910438537597656],[-76.99923706054688,38.91141128540039],[-76.9929428100586,38.91346740722656],[-76.99183654785156,38.91428756713867],[-76.98184967041016,38.91727828979492],[-76.97837829589844,38.91860580444336],[-76.9774398803711,38.91832733154297],[-76.95590209960938,38.917781829833984],[-76.94385528564453,38.9168701171875],[-76.94595336914062,38.915252685546875],[-76.95199584960938,38.9149055480957],[-76.95357513427734,38.91438293457031],[-76.95446014404297,38.91096115112305],[-76.95796966552734,38.90615463256836],[-76.95938873291016,38.90338897705078],[-76.96221923828125,38.899497985839844],[-76.96186065673828,38.895301818847656],[-76.96336364746094,38.88986587524414],[-76.97725677490234,38.88979721069336],[-76.97725677490234,38.89200210571289],[-76.98075866699219,38.89200973510742],[-76.98076629638672,38.889801025390625],[-76.98562622070312,38.889801025390625],[-76.98831176757812,38.89019012451172],[-76.98831939697266,38.889244079589844],[-76.99154663085938,38.889225006103516],[-76.99264526367188,38.88980484008789],[-77.00057983398438,38.889808654785156],[-77.00057983398438,38.89093780517578],[-77.00204467773438,38.89093780517578],[-77.00203704833984,38.889808654785156],[-77.0035171508789,38.889808654785156],[-77.00591278076172,38.88981246948242],[-77.00589752197266,38.887611389160156],[-77.00906372070312,38.88758850097656],[-77.01203155517578,38.8889274597168],[-77.0122299194336,38.89083480834961]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20005","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.03652954101562,38.907020568847656],[-77.03456115722656,38.9087028503418],[-77.03652954101562,38.908695220947266],[-77.03651428222656,38.91112518310547],[-77.02808380126953,38.91112518310547],[-77.02703857421875,38.9111213684082],[-77.02703857421875,38.89981460571289],[-77.028076171875,38.8983154296875],[-77.02703094482422,38.8983154296875],[-77.02703094482422,38.8973503112793],[-77.02961730957031,38.8973388671875],[-77.02961730957031,38.898311614990234],[-77.03195190429688,38.8983154296875],[-77.0319595336914,38.8973503112793],[-77.03364562988281,38.89734649658203],[-77.03511810302734,38.89876174926758],[-77.03459167480469,38.901336669921875],[-77.03654479980469,38.90252685546875],[-77.03652954101562,38.907020568847656]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20037","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.06937408447266,38.900367736816406],[-77.06275177001953,38.90203857421875],[-77.06279754638672,38.901065826416016],[-77.05743408203125,38.89966583251953],[-77.05753326416016,38.90028762817383],[-77.05859375,38.90133285522461],[-77.05360412597656,38.90849685668945],[-77.0501480102539,38.90963363647461],[-77.04879760742188,38.91041564941406],[-77.046630859375,38.91033935546875],[-77.04663848876953,38.90724563598633],[-77.0488052368164,38.9072380065918],[-77.04881286621094,38.905269622802734],[-77.04664611816406,38.90562438964844],[-77.04664611816406,38.903743743896484],[-77.04664611816406,38.90252685546875],[-77.04685974121094,38.9024772644043],[-77.048828125,38.902469635009766],[-77.048828125,38.9020881652832],[-77.0466537475586,38.90131759643555],[-77.0466537475586,38.900691986083984],[-77.04727172851562,38.90069580078125],[-77.04734802246094,38.89957809448242],[-77.0466537475586,38.89957809448242],[-77.04666137695312,38.89735412597656],[-77.04884338378906,38.897361755371094],[-77.04801940917969,38.89601516723633],[-77.05011749267578,38.89602279663086],[-77.05013275146484,38.893497467041016],[-77.04885864257812,38.89350128173828],[-77.0488510131836,38.8921012878418],[-77.0558853149414,38.892879486083984],[-77.05289459228516,38.89003372192383],[-77.05258178710938,38.88839340209961],[-77.0584945678711,38.88624572753906],[-77.06096649169922,38.88929748535156],[-77.06405639648438,38.890159606933594],[-77.06465911865234,38.891845703125],[-77.06729888916016,38.89921188354492],[-77.06819915771484,38.899810791015625],[-77.06937408447266,38.900367736816406]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20520","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.05011749267578,38.89602279663086],[-77.04801940917969,38.89601516723633],[-77.04668426513672,38.89531707763672],[-77.04667663574219,38.89350128173828],[-77.04885864257812,38.89350128173828],[-77.05013275146484,38.893497467041016],[-77.05011749267578,38.89602279663086]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20017","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.00868225097656,38.92823791503906],[-77.00697326660156,38.931209564208984],[-77.0060806274414,38.93427276611328],[-77.0080337524414,38.9423828125],[-77.00482940673828,38.94076156616211],[-77.00438690185547,38.94286346435547],[-77.00155639648438,38.94286346435547],[-77.00485229492188,38.94568634033203],[-77.0002670288086,38.94696044921875],[-77.00133514404297,38.949466705322266],[-77.00172424316406,38.95087814331055],[-76.99800872802734,38.95181655883789],[-76.99598693847656,38.951995849609375],[-76.99681854248047,38.952632904052734],[-76.99176788330078,38.953617095947266],[-76.99041748046875,38.95357131958008],[-76.98839569091797,38.95323944091797],[-76.98786926269531,38.9541015625],[-76.97843170166016,38.946807861328125],[-76.97782897949219,38.94633865356445],[-76.98037719726562,38.943214416503906],[-76.98020935058594,38.94071960449219],[-76.98199462890625,38.94071960449219],[-76.98043060302734,38.93923568725586],[-76.98408508300781,38.93927001953125],[-76.98287200927734,38.93492889404297],[-76.9823226928711,38.92802047729492],[-76.98403930664062,38.92793273925781],[-76.98388671875,38.92607116699219],[-76.98580169677734,38.925697326660156],[-76.98644256591797,38.92456817626953],[-76.98799896240234,38.923866271972656],[-76.98811340332031,38.92558288574219],[-76.9946517944336,38.92558288574219],[-76.99513244628906,38.923797607421875],[-76.99563598632812,38.92536163330078],[-76.99620056152344,38.922332763671875],[-77.00057220458984,38.92237091064453],[-77.00057220458984,38.92559051513672],[-77.00629425048828,38.92700958251953],[-77.00894165039062,38.92667770385742],[-77.00868225097656,38.92823791503906]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20535","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.0260009765625,38.89483642578125],[-77.02397155761719,38.89479446411133],[-77.02397155761719,38.89387512207031],[-77.0260009765625,38.89444351196289],[-77.0260009765625,38.89483642578125]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20565","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.02189636230469,38.8920783996582],[-77.01991271972656,38.89207458496094],[-77.0198974609375,38.892757415771484],[-77.01518249511719,38.891448974609375],[-77.01757049560547,38.890594482421875],[-77.01756286621094,38.888797760009766],[-77.02190399169922,38.888736724853516],[-77.02189636230469,38.8920783996582]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20551","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.04667663574219,38.89350128173828],[-77.044921875,38.89350891113281],[-77.04493713378906,38.8921012878418],[-77.04667663574219,38.8921012878418],[-77.04667663574219,38.89350128173828]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20018","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.0013427734375,38.910438537597656],[-76.99513244628906,38.923797607421875],[-76.9946517944336,38.92558288574219],[-76.98811340332031,38.92558288574219],[-76.98799896240234,38.923866271972656],[-76.98644256591797,38.92456817626953],[-76.98580169677734,38.925697326660156],[-76.98388671875,38.92607116699219],[-76.98403930664062,38.92793273925781],[-76.9823226928711,38.92802047729492],[-76.98287200927734,38.93492889404297],[-76.98408508300781,38.93927001953125],[-76.98043060302734,38.93923568725586],[-76.98199462890625,38.94071960449219],[-76.98020935058594,38.94071960449219],[-76.98037719726562,38.943214416503906],[-76.97782897949219,38.94633865356445],[-76.95874786376953,38.93159484863281],[-76.9419174194336,38.91858673095703],[-76.94293212890625,38.91740036010742],[-76.94385528564453,38.9168701171875],[-76.95590209960938,38.917781829833984],[-76.9774398803711,38.91832733154297],[-76.97837829589844,38.91860580444336],[-76.98184967041016,38.91727828979492],[-76.99183654785156,38.91428756713867],[-76.9929428100586,38.91346740722656],[-76.99923706054688,38.91141128540039],[-77.0013427734375,38.910438537597656]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20016","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.11975860595703,38.93434143066406],[-77.10449981689453,38.9464111328125],[-77.10070037841797,38.948909759521484],[-77.09149932861328,38.95650863647461],[-77.09099578857422,38.9568977355957],[-77.09073638916016,38.957096099853516],[-77.09014129638672,38.95644760131836],[-77.08617401123047,38.957054138183594],[-77.07410430908203,38.95658874511719],[-77.07152557373047,38.952171325683594],[-77.07249450683594,38.94869613647461],[-77.07242584228516,38.93815612792969],[-77.0705795288086,38.939090728759766],[-77.06829833984375,38.939083099365234],[-77.06639099121094,38.93815231323242],[-77.0663833618164,38.927528381347656],[-77.0773696899414,38.92752456665039],[-77.07896423339844,38.92628860473633],[-77.08094024658203,38.9282112121582],[-77.08151245117188,38.92615509033203],[-77.0826187133789,38.92786407470703],[-77.09355163574219,38.92756271362305],[-77.09452819824219,38.92578887939453],[-77.09650421142578,38.92582321166992],[-77.09876251220703,38.922332763671875],[-77.09857940673828,38.92115020751953],[-77.10195922851562,38.919952392578125],[-77.10191345214844,38.91861343383789],[-77.1050033569336,38.91633605957031],[-77.1063003540039,38.91910934448242],[-77.1134033203125,38.92521286010742],[-77.1166000366211,38.92890930175781],[-77.11681365966797,38.92949295043945],[-77.1178970336914,38.932411193847656],[-77.11975860595703,38.93434143066406]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20053","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.01299285888672,38.88667297363281],[-77.01078796386719,38.88507843017578],[-77.00906372070312,38.88506317138672],[-77.00910949707031,38.882080078125],[-77.0122299194336,38.882991790771484],[-77.01253509521484,38.884586334228516],[-77.01348114013672,38.886268615722656],[-77.01299285888672,38.88667297363281]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20009","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.05021667480469,38.921302795410156],[-77.0487289428711,38.922462463378906],[-77.04898834228516,38.92498016357422],[-77.04962921142578,38.928165435791016],[-77.04605865478516,38.92605209350586],[-77.04478454589844,38.927452087402344],[-77.04411315917969,38.92702102661133],[-77.04336547851562,38.92797088623047],[-77.0442123413086,38.929561614990234],[-77.04214477539062,38.92844772338867],[-77.02970886230469,38.92863464355469],[-77.02740478515625,38.928287506103516],[-77.02704620361328,38.92675018310547],[-77.02703857421875,38.91260528564453],[-77.02808380126953,38.91112518310547],[-77.03651428222656,38.91112518310547],[-77.046630859375,38.911128997802734],[-77.046630859375,38.9126091003418],[-77.04755401611328,38.9126091003418],[-77.04608917236328,38.914432525634766],[-77.04622650146484,38.91584014892578],[-77.04752349853516,38.918304443359375],[-77.04887390136719,38.91898727416992],[-77.05021667480469,38.921302795410156]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20230","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.03340911865234,38.8955078125],[-77.03195190429688,38.89550018310547],[-77.03196716308594,38.892093658447266],[-77.03365325927734,38.89208984375],[-77.03340911865234,38.8955078125]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20593","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.013671875,38.8646240234375],[-77.01089477539062,38.86468505859375],[-77.01012420654297,38.86728286743164],[-77.00907135009766,38.86728286743164],[-77.0090560913086,38.870079040527344],[-77.00916290283203,38.87069320678711],[-77.00888061523438,38.87080383300781],[-77.0082015991211,38.869911193847656],[-77.00741577148438,38.8695068359375],[-77.01060485839844,38.86489486694336],[-77.01176452636719,38.8636474609375],[-77.01367950439453,38.863525390625],[-77.013671875,38.8646240234375]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20032","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-77.02786254882812,38.81615447998047],[-77.02696990966797,38.826324462890625],[-77.02620697021484,38.82991409301758],[-77.0246810913086,38.83310317993164],[-77.02356719970703,38.83430480957031],[-77.02427673339844,38.83534240722656],[-77.0230712890625,38.84040451049805],[-77.02127075195312,38.84602355957031],[-77.01911163330078,38.85017776489258],[-77.01897430419922,38.850433349609375],[-77.01667785644531,38.852989196777344],[-77.01526641845703,38.85590744018555],[-77.01318359375,38.85744857788086],[-77.01233673095703,38.85684585571289],[-77.01072692871094,38.8580436706543],[-77.0100326538086,38.855506896972656],[-77.01146697998047,38.85249328613281],[-77.0135726928711,38.85100555419922],[-77.0090103149414,38.84994125366211],[-77.00813293457031,38.84817123413086],[-77.00865936279297,38.850135803222656],[-77.0069580078125,38.85296630859375],[-77.0047378540039,38.85872268676758],[-77.00344848632812,38.860687255859375],[-77.0026626586914,38.860294342041016],[-77.00423431396484,38.85320281982422],[-77.00324249267578,38.85151672363281],[-76.99856567382812,38.852256774902344],[-76.9988021850586,38.85329818725586],[-76.99605560302734,38.85506820678711],[-76.99607849121094,38.8560676574707],[-76.98504638671875,38.84896469116211],[-76.98922729492188,38.844566345214844],[-76.98280334472656,38.84617614746094],[-76.98271942138672,38.84733963012695],[-76.98055267333984,38.84758758544922],[-76.98133087158203,38.84659957885742],[-76.9789047241211,38.84218978881836],[-76.9772720336914,38.841922760009766],[-76.97284698486328,38.8431510925293],[-76.97816467285156,38.83888244628906],[-76.97949981689453,38.83781051635742],[-76.9926986694336,38.82821273803711],[-77.0,38.82191467285156],[-77.00139617919922,38.82151412963867],[-77.02245330810547,38.80479431152344],[-77.02421569824219,38.80339050292969],[-77.02313995361328,38.80584716796875],[-77.02279663085938,38.80946350097656],[-77.0257797241211,38.81061935424805],[-77.02704620361328,38.81417465209961],[-77.02880859375,38.815330505371094],[-77.02786254882812,38.81615447998047]]],[[[-77.03097534179688,38.811195373535156],[-77.02915954589844,38.80901336669922],[-77.0297622680664,38.80851364135742],[-77.03077697753906,38.80854797363281],[-77.03128814697266,38.80836486816406],[-77.03097534179688,38.811195373535156]]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20006","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.04884338378906,38.897361755371094],[-77.04666137695312,38.89735412597656],[-77.0466537475586,38.89957809448242],[-77.0466537475586,38.900691986083984],[-77.0466537475586,38.90131759643555],[-77.04664611816406,38.90252685546875],[-77.04664611816406,38.903743743896484],[-77.0448989868164,38.90252685546875],[-77.04345703125,38.903743743896484],[-77.04168701171875,38.90252685546875],[-77.03654479980469,38.90252685546875],[-77.03459167480469,38.901336669921875],[-77.03511810302734,38.89876174926758],[-77.03510284423828,38.895816802978516],[-77.03795623779297,38.89539337158203],[-77.0379867553711,38.89863967895508],[-77.03925323486328,38.89874267578125],[-77.03946685791016,38.8953971862793],[-77.03948211669922,38.8921012878418],[-77.04173278808594,38.8921012878418],[-77.04347229003906,38.89351272583008],[-77.04668426513672,38.89531707763672],[-77.04801940917969,38.89601516723633],[-77.04884338378906,38.897361755371094]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20001","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.02808380126953,38.91112518310547],[-77.02703857421875,38.91260528564453],[-77.02704620361328,38.92675018310547],[-77.02740478515625,38.928287506103516],[-77.01956176757812,38.92927932739258],[-77.01798248291016,38.92844772338867],[-77.0167465209961,38.92753601074219],[-77.01403045654297,38.926273345947266],[-77.00894165039062,38.92667770385742],[-77.00902557373047,38.91078186035156],[-77.00900268554688,38.90727233886719],[-77.01216125488281,38.90626907348633],[-77.01026916503906,38.9056510925293],[-77.0110092163086,38.903785705566406],[-77.00906372070312,38.90372848510742],[-77.00906372070312,38.90131378173828],[-77.01216125488281,38.90131759643555],[-77.01217651367188,38.90019989013672],[-77.00906372070312,38.90020751953125],[-77.00906372070312,38.89479064941406],[-77.0071792602539,38.8947868347168],[-77.00757598876953,38.89362716674805],[-77.00817108154297,38.89202880859375],[-77.00822448730469,38.89141082763672],[-77.0122299194336,38.89083480834961],[-77.01518249511719,38.891448974609375],[-77.0198974609375,38.892757415771484],[-77.0198974609375,38.8973388671875],[-77.02191925048828,38.89727783203125],[-77.02191162109375,38.89844512939453],[-77.02703094482422,38.8983154296875],[-77.028076171875,38.8983154296875],[-77.02703857421875,38.89981460571289],[-77.02703857421875,38.9111213684082],[-77.02808380126953,38.91112518310547]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20036","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.0488052368164,38.9072380065918],[-77.04663848876953,38.90724563598633],[-77.046630859375,38.91033935546875],[-77.046630859375,38.911128997802734],[-77.03651428222656,38.91112518310547],[-77.03652954101562,38.908695220947266],[-77.03456115722656,38.9087028503418],[-77.03652954101562,38.907020568847656],[-77.03654479980469,38.90252685546875],[-77.04168701171875,38.90252685546875],[-77.04345703125,38.903743743896484],[-77.0448989868164,38.90252685546875],[-77.04664611816406,38.903743743896484],[-77.04664611816406,38.90562438964844],[-77.04881286621094,38.905269622802734],[-77.0488052368164,38.9072380065918]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20240","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.04347229003906,38.8953971862793],[-77.0417251586914,38.89540481567383],[-77.04174041748047,38.89352798461914],[-77.04347229003906,38.89351272583008],[-77.04347229003906,38.8953971862793]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20317","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.01903533935547,38.93739700317383],[-77.01741027832031,38.93788146972656],[-77.01092529296875,38.94461441040039],[-77.0080337524414,38.9423828125],[-77.0060806274414,38.93427276611328],[-77.00697326660156,38.931209564208984],[-77.01509857177734,38.93111038208008],[-77.01828002929688,38.93055725097656],[-77.01922607421875,38.93689727783203],[-77.01903533935547,38.93739700317383]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20510","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.00757598876953,38.89362716674805],[-77.00588989257812,38.89362335205078],[-77.00590515136719,38.89201354980469],[-77.00817108154297,38.89202880859375],[-77.00757598876953,38.89362716674805]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20560","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.02806854248047,38.888648986816406],[-77.0274887084961,38.8886833190918],[-77.026123046875,38.88906478881836],[-77.0255126953125,38.88903045654297],[-77.02399444580078,38.88871383666992],[-77.02401733398438,38.88756561279297],[-77.028076171875,38.88756561279297],[-77.02806854248047,38.888648986816406]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20057","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.07901763916016,38.91267776489258],[-77.0730972290039,38.91259002685547],[-77.07152557373047,38.90583801269531],[-77.07801818847656,38.905921936035156],[-77.07959747314453,38.90681457519531],[-77.07901763916016,38.91267776489258]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20245","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.04668426513672,38.89531707763672],[-77.04347229003906,38.89351272583008],[-77.04173278808594,38.8921012878418],[-77.04493713378906,38.8921012878418],[-77.044921875,38.89350891113281],[-77.04667663574219,38.89350128173828],[-77.04668426513672,38.89531707763672]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20003","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.01065063476562,38.872032165527344],[-77.00908660888672,38.872032165527344],[-77.00910949707031,38.88154983520508],[-77.00910949707031,38.882080078125],[-77.00906372070312,38.88506317138672],[-77.00906372070312,38.88758850097656],[-77.00589752197266,38.887611389160156],[-77.00588989257812,38.88603973388672],[-77.0035171508789,38.88603973388672],[-77.0035171508789,38.88761520385742],[-77.0035171508789,38.88915252685547],[-77.0035171508789,38.889808654785156],[-77.00203704833984,38.889808654785156],[-77.00204467773438,38.89093780517578],[-77.00057983398438,38.89093780517578],[-77.00057983398438,38.889808654785156],[-76.99264526367188,38.88980484008789],[-76.99154663085938,38.889225006103516],[-76.98831939697266,38.889244079589844],[-76.98831176757812,38.89019012451172],[-76.98562622070312,38.889801025390625],[-76.98076629638672,38.889801025390625],[-76.98075866699219,38.89200973510742],[-76.97725677490234,38.89200210571289],[-76.97725677490234,38.88979721069336],[-76.96336364746094,38.88986587524414],[-76.96678924560547,38.88523483276367],[-76.9696044921875,38.882659912109375],[-76.97329711914062,38.87839126586914],[-76.97802734375,38.87688064575195],[-76.98395538330078,38.87492752075195],[-76.99029541015625,38.87120819091797],[-76.99246215820312,38.8701286315918],[-76.9954833984375,38.87007141113281],[-77.00341796875,38.87087631225586],[-77.00545501708984,38.86870574951172],[-77.00741577148438,38.8695068359375],[-77.0082015991211,38.869911193847656],[-77.00888061523438,38.87080383300781],[-77.00916290283203,38.87069320678711],[-77.0090560913086,38.870079040527344],[-77.00907135009766,38.86728286743164],[-77.01012420654297,38.86728286743164],[-77.01068878173828,38.86824417114258],[-77.01065063476562,38.872032165527344]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20045","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.0319595336914,38.8973503112793],[-77.02961730957031,38.8973388671875],[-77.0296401977539,38.89612579345703],[-77.0319595336914,38.8961067199707],[-77.0319595336914,38.8973503112793]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20373","city":"Naval anacost annex","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.01897430419922,38.850433349609375],[-77.01538848876953,38.857364654541016],[-77.01382446289062,38.858619689941406],[-77.00767517089844,38.86223602294922],[-77.00369262695312,38.868011474609375],[-77.00239562988281,38.86747360229492],[-77.0017318725586,38.86482620239258],[-77.0020751953125,38.862754821777344],[-77.00344848632812,38.860687255859375],[-77.0047378540039,38.85872268676758],[-77.0069580078125,38.85296630859375],[-77.00865936279297,38.850135803222656],[-77.00813293457031,38.84817123413086],[-77.0090103149414,38.84994125366211],[-77.0135726928711,38.85100555419922],[-77.01146697998047,38.85249328613281],[-77.0100326538086,38.855506896972656],[-77.01072692871094,38.8580436706543],[-77.01233673095703,38.85684585571289],[-77.01318359375,38.85744857788086],[-77.01526641845703,38.85590744018555],[-77.01667785644531,38.852989196777344],[-77.01897430419922,38.850433349609375]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20064","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.00298309326172,38.94074249267578],[-76.99754333496094,38.940731048583984],[-76.99472045898438,38.934322357177734],[-76.99506378173828,38.933624267578125],[-77.00098419189453,38.93121337890625],[-77.00130462646484,38.93181228637695],[-77.00298309326172,38.94074249267578]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20553","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.02401733398438,38.88756561279297],[-77.02191925048828,38.8875617980957],[-77.02191925048828,38.887386322021484],[-77.02191162109375,38.886322021484375],[-77.0240249633789,38.88633346557617],[-77.02401733398438,38.88756561279297]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":"20010","city":"Washington","county":"District of columbia","state":"DC"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-77.05058288574219,38.93326950073242],[-77.03563690185547,38.93861770629883],[-77.03380584716797,38.937618255615234],[-77.02313995361328,38.93764877319336],[-77.02308654785156,38.936622619628906],[-77.02140808105469,38.93769836425781],[-77.01898956298828,38.93777084350586],[-77.01903533935547,38.93739700317383],[-77.01922607421875,38.93689727783203],[-77.01828002929688,38.93055725097656],[-77.01509857177734,38.93111038208008],[-77.00697326660156,38.931209564208984],[-77.00868225097656,38.92823791503906],[-77.00894165039062,38.92667770385742],[-77.01403045654297,38.926273345947266],[-77.0167465209961,38.92753601074219],[-77.01798248291016,38.92844772338867],[-77.01956176757812,38.92927932739258],[-77.02740478515625,38.928287506103516],[-77.02970886230469,38.92863464355469],[-77.04214477539062,38.92844772338867],[-77.0442123413086,38.929561614990234],[-77.04336547851562,38.92797088623047],[-77.04411315917969,38.92702102661133],[-77.04478454589844,38.927452087402344],[-77.0471420288086,38.931419372558594],[-77.05066680908203,38.93229293823242],[-77.05058288574219,38.93326950073242]]],[[[-77.05645751953125,38.936946868896484],[-77.05451965332031,38.9368782043457],[-77.054443359375,38.936866760253906],[-77.05413055419922,38.936767578125],[-77.05540466308594,38.936370849609375],[-77.05645751953125,38.936946868896484]]]]}}]}
```